# How can I get a empty list when I use the enumerate before the loop?

Tags: python

salary_data is a list in python.When I used the enumerate function in the loop like below,everything went well.

```
##salary_data = enumerate(salary_data)
max_label = [i for i,x in enumerate(salary_data) if x==max(salary_data)]
print max_label
```

but When I use the enumerate function like below,I got a salary_data which is a empty list,and ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence.I don't know Why.

```
salary_data = enumerate(salary_data)
max_label = [i for i,x in salary_data if x==max(salary_data)]
print max_label
```

Comment: You threw away the original `salary_data`, so `x==max(salary_data)` is calling `max` on the wrong thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enumerate(salary_data)` is an iterator because you wrapped it in an `enumerate`. That means it will be exhausted (empty) when you call `max` on it (besides the giving the *wrong* maximum).

You should calculate the max up front (avoiding recalculation) and then you could also iterate over the `enumerate`d data:

```
max_ = max(salary_data)  # avoids repeated maximum calculation in the loop
salary_data_enumerated = enumerate(salary_data)  # other variable name, for readability
max_label = [i for i, x in salary_data_enumerated if x==max_]
```